# How to watch videos on Sony Bravia TV through LAN?

Tags: lan, tv

I have recently bought a [Sony Bravia 40EX520](http://www.sony.co.in/product/kdl-40ex520).

To watch videos on it I need to copy them to a USB drive, which is a time-consuming process.

As there is connectivity of LAN for the TV, can I watch the videos directly if they are shared on a computer within the LAN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your TV seems to access media over [DLNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dlna), a technology which allows you to stream media over the network. In order to have access to the videos, your computer needs to become a DLNA server, which the TV should detect automatically, once they are in the same network.

#### Step 1 – Install a DLNA server on your PC

You didn't specify your operating system, and [there are many](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/21-how-to-choose-dlna-media-server-windows-mac-os-x-or-linux) DLNA servers for Windows alone. That being said, I personally use [**TVMobili**](http://www.tvmobili.com/). It is freely available for almost all platforms and seems to support a large number of media formats and client devices.

Once installed, you need to tell it where your videos are. Add them to TVMobili's library.

#### Step 2 – Connect the TV to the DLNA Server

Once TVMobili has scanned your videos, you'll be able to access them over your TV. You will need to:

- Plug in the LAN cable and configure the TV so it can "see" the computer in the LAN
- Start up the DLNA Server (TVMobili) if you haven't done yet
- Connect to the DLNA Server. Consider reading the TV's manual for further details on how to do this.
- You should see an interface where you can browse your videos by name, date or folder. This interface can be configured within TVMobilis settings.

Comment: [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) is also very very popular these days, but just search for DLNA media servers and you should find something that suits your needs.

Comment: thanks for the quick ans ... my pc uses WinXP and laptop has Win7 ... i ll test it after reaching home and let u know if hav any problems ...

Comment: thanku very much... dat was working like charm... i hav got one doubt.. my sony bravia doesnot recognize mkv files(more used often nw) so when my dlna server lists a mkv file can i play it on my tv ???

Comment: I see what you mean... MKVs are tricky. They have to be supported by the TV *and* the DLNA server. I can play MKV files fine (I have TVMobili too), but probably because my Samsung TV supports it. I don't know the specifics of your TV, but you might want to try and see if there's a firmware upgrade or search for MKV compatibility online.

Comment: my TV doesnot support MKV i tried using USB... my question whether DLNA server can render it at runtime to TV or not... i thnk dats nt posible.. nyways thnks for ur help it was gr8... :)

Comment: I'm afraid both will have to support it, I was having the same issues as you. Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows 10, you can:

- Enter "media streaming options" in Cortana
- Enable media streaming

To watch a video, you can

- Right click on the video
- Select "cast to device"

Comment: Nearly 6 years ago OP did not have windows 10

Comment: @yass: That is true, but I'm answering today, and my answer may help other people who have this question. Such as the myself of several hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Another option worth a shot is [TVersity](http://tversity.com/)

[image]